# Call different callback from AsyncTask onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implemented an internal AsyncTask for my class that does initial setup data query from server and stores into device cache. The setup data in split between 2 JSON files. The first JSON is read/cached and if certain conditions are on then second JSON file will be downloaded and stored into cache. I want to use same AsyncTask from both operations.

In doInBackground(), I perform JSON download operation independent of JSON type. But in onPostExecute() I want to call different callbacks depending if its 1st JSON file or second, since they require different handling. Is that possible?

EDIT: Pls note I do not want to use booleans, enum to decide which callback to call as in future I will have more files to process. From my calling class I want to set the callback and rest should happen automatically.

Comment: i think its possible since onPostExcite() will run on mainUithread but try something if not working post logcat

Comment: sure is it. for example set an boolean in your do in background and switch in onPostExecute() if 1st JSON or 2nd JSON ...

Answer (score 1):

Below implementation should solve your problem:

```
private class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private boolean mShouldCallMethod1;

        public MyCustomAsyncTask(boolean shouldCallMethod1){
            mShouldCallMethod1 = shouldCallMethod1;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //code goes here..
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(mShouldCallMethod1){
                method1();
            }else{
                method2();  
            }
        }

    }
```

i.e have a customized `AsyncTask` as innerclass.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I don't want to use boolean to decide the interface since in future I might have to do more than 2 file read/cache.

Comment: Instead of boolean, you could pass callback listener. In order to support more than 2 file read/cache, you could pass listeners specific to each read/cache..Or you could maintain an enum, and have  a single callback with enum as one of argument to  decide type of read/cache:)

Comment: Do you have code snippet to pass different callback listeners? I have come across code where I can implement an interface, but even in that case unless I have different classes using the asynctask it doesn't help the case.

Comment: It looks like 1 to 1 discussion wrt more specific problem solving which doesn't seems will help the community in general. Please look for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same interface which contains the two callbacks this is no problem. Simply declare an interface with 2 callback methods (json1, json2) and pass an instance of the interface to the AsyncTask. 
In your onPostExecute() you can call the callback(s).

Comment: PieterAelse: I would still need to put some logic like a boolean or something in onPostExcute  that decides which of the 2 callbacks between json1 and json2 to be called?

Comment: Yes you have. "if certain conditions" => boolean or check Json or something to decide what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As android does not support setListner Methods for onPostExccute so there is two ways:

1. Extend AsychTask and imlement setOnPostExcuteListner
2. Or just call "your method" from onPostExcute simple!