# Doing different things after AsyncTask executes?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hi I am still relatively new to android programming and I recently stumbled upon a rather abstract question on AsyncTasks.

To my understanding, after AsyncTask executes runInBackground, it returns a value to onPostExecute, where it does UI thread things with the result. Now, what if I want to do different things with the result returned from runInBackground. I've seen proposed examples such as this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907478/call-different-callback-from-asynctask-onpostexecute)):

```
private class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private boolean mShouldCallMethod1;

    public MyCustomAsyncTask(boolean shouldCallMethod1){
        mShouldCallMethod1 = shouldCallMethod1;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //code goes here..
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(mShouldCallMethod1){
            method1();
        }else{
            method2();  
        }
    }

}
```

But what if I want more than two things that onPostExecute should do (such as a method3, method4, and so on? Sure, I can implement a `switch` and some int variables to determine what method to call, etc, but that seems quite dumb and redundant. The model of a function returning a result regardless of its purpose seems much straight-forward to me. Yet in AsyncTask, it seems like I have to designate a purpose. And I was wondering if there is a way that AsyncTask can achieve something like what a function does.

For example I have an AsyncTask that fetches an image with a URL. And this image may be used to populate an `ImageView`, or it may be saved to the gallery. So they essentially do the the same exact thing in `runInBackground`, but their results need to be handled differently.

I am still a beginner so I apologize if I missed some simple detail/concept.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should write different Asynctasks if they do different things

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for replying. Yes I have thought about that, but that means I would have to write a bunch of the same things over and over, which also seems redundant. Though if there's no other way around, that will have to do.

Comment: The answer really depends on what you're trying to achieve, and the code sample provided is too arbitrary. What data will the AsyncTask be supplying as an argument `onPostExecute`? I assume it will be of the same type, so what needs to change in the way it's handled?

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks for replying. I apologize for the ambiguity. Yes, the data that `onPostExecute` gets is of the same type. I don't have any specific code samples, but I will provide an simple example in the original question.

Comment: Stop using AsyncTasks already :trollface:. There are much better alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think a switch is dumb, you have good OO instincts.  And there are good reasons to avoid `AsyncTask` in general.  But putting that aside and focusing on your question...

If you have a bunch of `AsyncTask`s that do the same thing in `doInBackground` but need to do different things in `onPostExecute`, this is a classic case for anonymous subclassing.  First, implement `doInBackground` in your `MyCustomAsyncTask`.  Then in your `Activity` or wherever you need to use it, declare and use the anonymous subclass.

```
mAsyncTask = new MyCustomAsyncTask(/* constructor params */) {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // can access activity members here
        mAsyncTask = null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Make sure a running task is canceled in `onPause` or `onDestroy`.

```
if(mAsyncTask != null) {
    mAsyncTask.cancel();
    mAsyncTask = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have never seen this solution after digging around a lot of similar questions (maybe not enough). It looks like exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Where you call the asyncTask from will determine the use to which you put the image. You return the image to that point and use it for the purpose you made the call.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Dumb question: how am I supposed to "return" the image back to the original point where I called the AsyncTask, aren't they on different threads?

Comment: This was answered by Fencer300 earlier today, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858053/confused-on-how-to-make-variable-in-class/44858357#44858357

Comment: Also potentially  helpful was my question about race conditions and helpful answer by  Gabe Sechan. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864075/can-doinbackground-in-an-asynctask-potentially-cause-a-race-condition

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede's anonymous subclass solution above is neat.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I have seen the `.get()` solution. However, I've noticed that some say that it freezes up the UI thread (not sure)?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the .get() aspect as that does make the UI thread wait, rather Fencer300 bean serialization solution.

Comment: Using the subclass solution from Kevin Krumwiede it will not be an issue anyway as overriding the onPostExecute achieves your need for differing post doinbackground actions. Very cool.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misinterpretation. Thanks for the input anyways.